# mvn package is failing -Class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport does not have member field 'com.sun.tool

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, jar

Error:  - [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project StockGuardian: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport does not have member field 'com.sun.tool

My pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.java.Abhas</groupId>
    <artifactId>StockGuardian</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>StockGuardian</name>
    <description>Creating a sample project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1022</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
             <version>1.18.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i searched on google and chatgpt but not able to generate the jar file. Need help

Comment: Remove the `maven-dependency-plugin` and `maven-compiler-plugin`. Proper versions are already pulled in by the `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Comment: still getting same error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project StockGuardian: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport does not have member field 'com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree qualid' -> [Help 1]

Comment: `
<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <excludes>
      <exclude>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      </exclude>
     </excludes>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>`